# Создание одноразовых URL на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

Мне нужно создавать одноразовый URL который будет неактивен после перехода на него. Нет возможности использовать бд. Возможно кто-нибудь подскажет источник или скорректирует по библиотекам которые можно использовать?

Comment: Ого, а как же вы без бд будете сохранять информацию о переходе? Ну записывайте её в файл 

Comment: Это примитивная задача. Какие попытки вы предприняли чтобы её решить? Например, ну хотя бы какой алгоритм действий?

Comment: То что нет возможности её использовать не значит что её нет. в данный момент мне нужно понять как генерировать такие ссылки

Comment: Это в смысле на вашем веб сервере должно быть или куда переход то будет вообще?

Comment: Пользователю будет отправляться ссылка на форму

Comment: Ну так вот поймите тогда сначала. Логику распишите хотя бы, тут несколько простых шагов. Например, страница открылась, что дальше?

Comment: Пока что пробовал просто искать информацию об этом, думал спросить тут чтобы сразу скорректировали по инструментам

Comment: Никаких инструментов вам не понадобится, задача примитивная

Answer (score 2):

Код

```
from aiohttp import web
import uuid

routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes.get('/')
def genlink(request):
    orig = request.query.get('orig')
    uid = uuid.uuid4()
    url = f"/{uid.hex}"
    request.app.cache[uid]=orig
    return web.Response(text=url)

@routes.get('/{uid}')
def golink(request):
    uid = uuid.UUID(request.match_info.get('uid'))
    orig = request.app.cache.pop(uid, None)
    if orig:
        raise web.HTTPFound(location=orig)
    else:
        raise web.HTTPNotFound()

app = web.Application()
app.cache = dict()
app.add_routes(routes)
web.run_app(app)
```

Формируем ссылку

```
$ curl -vv "http://127.0.0.1:8080/?orig=http%3A%2F%2Fipinfo.io/ip"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /?orig=http%3A%2F%2Fipinfo.io/ip HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.82.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 33
< Date: Thu, 07 Apr 2022 09:40:33 GMT
< Server: Python/3.10 aiohttp/3.8.1
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
/b8b95ba24f764cf7873217cfa9e01cd7
```

И переход

```
$ curl -L -vv http://127.0.0.1:8080/b8b95ba24f764cf7873217cfa9e01cd7
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /b8b95ba24f764cf7873217cfa9e01cd7 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.82.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Location: http://ipinfo.io/ip
< Content-Length: 10
< Date: Thu, 07 Apr 2022 09:41:29 GMT
< Server: Python/3.10 aiohttp/3.8.1
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://ipinfo.io/ip'
*   Trying 34.117.59.81:80...
* Connected to ipinfo.io (34.117.59.81) port 80 (#1)
> GET /ip HTTP/1.1
> Host: ipinfo.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.82.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 13
< date: Thu, 07 Apr 2022 09:41:29 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1
< Via: 1.1 google
< 
* Connection #1 to host ipinfo.io left intact
9x.29.xxx.10x
```

А вот просрочка при повторе

```
$ curl -L -vv http://127.0.0.1:8080/b8b95ba24f764cf7873217cfa9e01cd7
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /b8b95ba24f764cf7873217cfa9e01cd7 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.82.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 14
< Date: Thu, 07 Apr 2022 09:41:56 GMT
< Server: Python/3.10 aiohttp/3.8.1
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
404: Not Found
```